# JS interactive map: display state names & create links

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to customize this map: http://jsfiddle.net/allankiezel/FJrNN/

What I am not able to do is:

1. Display the name or abbreviation of each state on mouseover
2. Link each state to a separate URL (instead of making it green on click)

JS code responsible for map's behavior:

```
var rsrGroups = [CA, OR, WA, NV, AZ, ID, UT, MT, WY, NM, CO, TX, NE, SD, ND, OK, KS, MN, IA, MO, AR, LA, WI, IL, MS, TN, KY, IN, AL, MI, FL, OH, GA, NC, VA, WV, SC, PA, MD, NJ, DE, VT, MA, CT, NH, ME, RI, NY, AK, HI];

for (var i = 0, len = rsrGroups.length; i <= len; i++) {

var el = rsrGroups[i];

el.mouseover(function() {
    this.toFront();
    this.attr({
        cursor: 'pointer',
        fill: '#990000',
        stroke: '#fff',
        'stroke-width': '2'
    });
    this.animate({
        scale: '1.2'
    }, 200);
});
el.mouseout(function() {
    this.animate({
        scale: '1.05'
    }, 200);
    this.attr({
        fill: '#003366'
    });
});
el.click(function() {
    this.animate({
        fill: 'green'
    }, 200);
});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to attach the attributes to the data first

```
CA.attr({
    fill: '#003366',
    id: 'CA',
    name: 'CA',
    href : 'http://www.california.com',
    title : 'California'
});
```

if you have these attributes you can access them in the mouseover function, now you have to determine where you want to show the tag, you could do this in a container or if you want to do this on the map you will have to set this place in the attributes too for each state.

you have to show the property on the state in the mouseover function and hide it in the mouseout function.

edit : If you want to show a tooltip you can simply set the attribute title
edit 2: set the properties to href and title, but it seems that the reference interfers with .toFront()